# How to link two 32-bit assembly files to a 32-bit dynamic library?

Tags: c, x86, clang, shared-libraries, llvm

I have been working an 32-bit machine recently. And I got two 32-bit `.s` files already via my own compiler which uses llvm as backend. When I try to link this two files to one dynamic library, error occurs.

```
clang++ -m32 test1.s test2.s -shared -fPIC -o test.so

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/test1-5ff028.o: relocation R_386_GOTOFF against undefined symbol `stdout@@GLIBC_2.0' can not be used when making a shared object
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The two `.s` files are generated from `llc -march=x86 xxx.ll --relocation-model=pic`.

And in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`, `glibc2.0` exists.

More about this, I can get exeutable files without `-shared`. And it works well.

```
clang++ -m32 test1.s test2.s -o test.out
./test.out # this can work fine
```

my coding env:

```
OS: WSL2 Ubuntu22.04 x86_64
clang: 13
llvm: 13
gcc-multilib/g++-multilib: installed
```

I tried to add `-lc -lm -ldl -lstdc++` and other flags, but no one worked.

How could I fix that?

Comment: You might try writing the equivalent code in C and compiling it with clang, and seeing what the difference is between clang and your compiler.

Comment: I *think* the GOT only exists in the main program and not in shared libraries, so it makes sense that GOT relocations wouldn't work in shared libraries. The question is why it is trying to use one. Maybe it needs to know that you are making a shared library.

Comment: I think that if the executable file can run fine, that means the compiler should be fine. About the main program, I try some simple demos which contain a main function and they can be linked to a shared libraries normally. So I thought it might not be a problem. But I don't know actually and probably I can't remove the main function either.